# UIDatePicker row height

Tags: ios, uikit, uidatepicker

I have a `UIDatePicker` in our app and I am attempting to change the row height.

`UIPickerView` has a delegate method `pickerView:rowHeightForComponent` but nothing for date pickers.

Is there any non-hacky way to change the row height?

Comment: you will have to implement your own picker — it isn't that hard, an example code I wrote: https://github.com/vikingosegundo/vsdatepicker

Comment: I was very much hoping I just missed something in the documentation.